# index.html won't be shown as a webpage in Firefox (Python2)

Tags: python, web-services, google-chrome, firefox

I am new to web servers. I have a simple web server which displays the index.html to client. I have tested it using Chrome and it is shown as an actual webpage. However, Firefox displays the index.html as an html file with tags. Here is python code for the server:

```
DataToSend=""
while True:
    data = f.read(4096)
    DataToSend=DataToSend+data
    if not data:
        break        
self.request.sendall(DataToSend)
f.close()
```

Here is the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example Page</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
        content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
        <!-- check conformance at http://validator.w3.org/check -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="base.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="eg">
        <h1>An Example Page</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>It works?
                        <li><a href="deep/index.html">A deeper page</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What web service framework are you using?

Comment: Or, if this is just raw socket code, say that, or, better yet, give us a [minimal, complete, valid example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which makes that obvious. (As a side note, it looks like SO just renamed that to "minimal, complete, tested, readable example", but left the URL as "mcve", only a short time after making us all switch from SSCCE… There's no way that's going to confuse anymore…)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't tell us what framework you were using. But I can guess the problem.

An HTTP response must consist of a response line, then the HTTP headers, then a blank line, then the body. Some frameworks just give you a file-like object that you can write whatever you want to, in which case you have to write all those bits. Others give you one API to set the response code, another to add headers, and another to set the body. But whatever you're using, clearly, the only thing you're sending anywhere is a body.

---

So, this could mean you're sending an invalid HTTP response. If this is just raw socket code, then clearly that's what's happening. And there are some frameworks where the same is true.

Browsers generally try to be tolerant of even severely broken servers, but they all do so in different ways, so it's not surprising that one would guess correctly and another would fail.

---

Or, it could mean that your framework is correctly sending a response code and some empty headers before your body, but those empty headers aren't enough to tell the browser what type of content it's supposed to deal with, and again one is guessing right and another isn't. (In particular, you should be sending a `Content-Type: text/html` header.)

You can see what you're sending pretty easily by talking to the server with a command-line tool—e.g., `echo GET / | nc server.host.name 80`, or `curl -D- http://server.host.name/` or whatever. That will tell you exactly what you're sending wrong.

But to figure out how to *fix* it, you'll need to read the tutorial for whatever framework you're using.

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer. I am using SocketServer. I have read the python SocketServer documentation, but could not find any useful information

Comment: @UlviIbrahimov: Well, `SocketServer` doesn't know how to do HTTP. If you want to write an HTTP server on top of raw sockets, you have to read [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html). It's a lot of work. That's why Python comes with `BaseHTTPServer`, `SimpleHTTPServer`, etc. as frameworks to build on, WSGI as a way to just plug your web app into a separate server, and dozens of third-party frameworks like Tornado, Twisted, gUnicorn, etc.

Comment: @UlviIbrahimov: If you really want to do it yourself, the source code to [`http.server`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/085a0ea2015f/Lib/http/server.py) (3.x) / [`SimpleHTTPServer`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/6eed57083a37/Lib/SimpleHTTPServer.py) (2.x) makes a decent sample to get you started, but you're going to need to be comfortable reading RFCs, experimenting with netcat, etc. if you expect to make this work.

Comment: @ abarnert, I will probably try different framework then and mark this answer as accepted. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The response type should be set as `text/html`